# Make Bluestacks 0.9.30 for Mac OS X Rooted

Tags: android, macos, bluestacks, rooted-device

How can I make my Bluestacks 0.9.30 for Mac OS X Rooted? I Try a lot of videos tutorial on youtube, but all is old and nor work for newest version of Bluestacks.